# Error when trashing oldest files in a directory. (gio trash error when used with xargs)

Tags: command-line, 20.04, xargs

In **18.04** I **was able** to **find** and **trash all but the newest** n (e.g. 8) **files** in a directory with:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -r | sed 1,8d | xargs -d \n gio trash
```

When I **try this** in a freshly installed **20.04** I get the **error**:

```
gio: file:///path/to/file.txt%0A: Error moving file /path/to/file.txt
 to the Rubbish Bin: No such file or directory
```

I **can manually trash** the same file **without error** using:

```
gio trash file.txt
```

What am I missing after the upgrade?

Comment: You might want to look at using `zsh` for this - its glob qualifiers allow you to select a range of files by modification time directly ex. `gio trash *(.Dom[9,-1])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The escape character `\n` is interpreted by bash before `xargs` runs because you did not quote it. So you tell `xargs` to cut items by `n`, not `\n`.

You want to put it in single quotes: `-d '\n'`.

To visualize the issue:

```bsh
# cut by n where you want newline:
$ printf 'a\nb' | xargs -d \n -I{} echo -{}-
-a
b-

# quote \n and it works:
$ printf 'a\nb' | xargs -d '\n' -I{} echo -{}-
-a-
-b-

# cut by "n" if you had n in your filename:
$ printf 'anb' | xargs -d \n -I{} echo -{}-
-a-
-b-
```

(I use `-I{} echo -{}-` to show the separated items, to reveal if/how the delimiter works)

---

While this will work, I would still advice against it

You should never use new line character to separate file names, because new line is a valid character for it.

Better use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | sort -rz | sed -z 1,8d | xargs -0 gio trash
```